# Postgres consulta por nombre de columnas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito saber que tablas tienen la columna_a y la columna_b.  La consulta que se me ocurre es:

```
select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name 
where c.column_name = 'columna_a'
and c.column_name = 'columna_b';
```

Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta correcta es:

```
select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name
       from information_schema.tables t
       inner join information_schema.columns c 
         on c.table_name = t.table_name 
         and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
       where c.column_name = 'columna_a'
             or c.column_name = 'columna_b'
       group by t.table_schema, t.table_name
       having count(1) = 2;
```

Gracias a Patricio Moracho por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es buscar las filas mediante un `OR` y asegurarte de recuperar solo las tablas que tengan dos ocurrencias (es decir que se le han encontrado las dos columnas)

```
select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name
       from information_schema.tables t
       inner join information_schema.columns c 
         on c.table_name = t.table_name 
       where c.column_name = 'columna_a'
             or c.column_name = 'columna_b'
       group by t.table_schema,
                t.table_name
       having count(1) = 2;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Patricio pero devuelve una u otra.  De todos modos creo que este es el camino, con el group by.  Voy a seguir probando.

Comment: No debiera ser así, revisa este ejemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/340e0/204. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Patricio era por ese camino.  Faltaba una condición en el inner join.  La consulta sería:  'select t.table_schema,
       t.table_name
       from information_schema.tables t
       inner join information_schema.columns c 
         on c.table_name = t.table_name and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
       where c.column_name = 'columna_a'
             or c.column_name = 'columna_b'
    group by t.table_schema, t.table_name
       having count(1) = 2;'          No se si es correcto agregarla  aquí como solución.  Gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score -1):

Con este método puedes obtener todas las tablas.

```
select table_schema,table_name,column_name,data_type
from information_schema.columns
order by column_name;
```

Allí puedes encontrar el dato que buscas.